# how to change the email sender name of email from firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

currently the email from authentication using firebase auth will be on spam folder of my gmail like this

[image]

I suspect it is because I use robot as the the name of email sender (robot@kumpulmuslimindonesia.firebaseapp.com) . but unfortunately I forget how to change this name. I believe previously it is in firebase project settings, but I can't find it know

Answer (score 3):

Firebase has a [support article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?hl=en) that describes how to do this.

> **Customize the sender domain**
>
> To specify a sender address with a custom domain:
>
> 1. Click an email type.
> 2. Click the pencil icon to begin editing the email template.
> 3. Click customize domain.
> 4. Specify the domain you want to use and follow the provided instructions to verify that you own the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Authentication > Templates > Password reset. There you should change 'Sender name'. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsWfZ.png)