# Changes in Firebase Authentication Email Verification "Sender Name" & "Reply To " are not Reflected

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The changes I've made in email address verification settings: "sender name", "Reply to" and "Subject"
are not reflected in the verification email create by firebase.

Here are the differences with the verification email received:

- sender name in email is `noreply` instead of my `customsendername`. Resulting in email being `noreply@mycustomdomain.com` instead of `mycustomsendername@mycustomdomain.com`
- reply to is `noreply@mycustomdomain.com` instead of the custom reply email I've set
- email subject is `Sign in to %APP_NAME%` instead of my custom subject set

For a visual representation, here are captions of the firebase email settings and the email received:

[image: firebase auth email settings]

[image: firebase auth email]

**Disclaimer: I've already successfully updated my custom domain. My target is the custom fields not being changed in email. This post is not a duplicate of [how to change the email sender name of email from firebase authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692099/how-to-change-the-email-sender-name-of-email-from-firebase-authentication)**